# Proxy blocks file - manual download works. Gradle still not working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proxy

I'm simply trying to install android studio. Unfortunately my gradle isn't working properly.

The configure build is always failing and throws the error:
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'. Received status code 407'

I can download the file manually without any problem. (but don't know where to put it so android studio will find it)

I even restarted android studio several times, downloaded gradle locally and put the http proxy on auto detect proxy settings.

Comment: If I check the URL connection on the proxy settings it also says that the connection is available.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTP status code 407](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/407) indicates that a proxy authentication is required. Have a look at the documentation on how to do [proxy authentication](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) for Gradle as the details really depend on the expected proxy authentication scheme.